# After Resume Thread not Stop Processing

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

Why am I not able to stop/ terminate my running thread and able to Pause and Resume. I have, a class `MyThreadProcessor` implements `Runnable` interface:

```
public class MyThreadProcessor implements Runnable {
private volatile boolean running = true;
private volatile boolean paused = false;
private List<String> pauseLock = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        synchronized (pauseLock) {
            if (!running) {
                 break;
            }
            if (paused) {
                try {
                    pauseLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    break;
                }
                if (!running) { // running might have changed since we paused
                    break;
                }
            }//if(paused)
        }//syncronized
        try {
            System.err.println("Sleeping...");
            Thread.sleep((long) 5000);
            System.err.println("Processing");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception"+ e);
            running = false;
        }
    }//while
}//run()

public void terminate() {
    running = false;
}
public void pause() {
    paused = true;
}
public void resume() {
    synchronized (pauseLock) {
        paused = false;
        pauseLock.notifyAll(); // Unblocks thread
    }
  }
}
```

and a MyTreadInitializer class like,

```
public class MyTreadInitializer {
private Thread thread = null;
private IndexProcessor runnable = null;

public void startMyTread() {
    runnable = new IndexProcessor();
    thread = new Thread(runnable);
    System.err.println("Starting thread: " + thread);
    thread.start();
    System.err.println("Background process successfully started.");
}

public void stopMyTread() {
    System.err.println("Stopping thread: " + thread);
    if (thread != null) {
        runnable.terminate();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception In Main"+ e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.err.println("Thread successfully stopped.");
    }
}

public void pauseMyTread() {
    System.err.println("Pausing thread: " + thread);
     if (thread != null) {
         runnable.pause();
      
         System.err.println("Thread successfully Paused.");
     }

}

public void resumeMyTread() {
    System.err.println("Resume thread: " + thread);
    if (thread != null) {
        runnable.resume();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("Exception In Pause"+ e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.err.println("Thread successfully stopped.");
    }
}
}
```

and main class is,

```
public class MyMainTH {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyTreadInitializer mi = new MyTreadInitializer();
    try {
    mi.startMyTread();
    Thread.sleep(15000);
    mi.pauseMyTread();  
    System.out.println("After Pause before Sleep");
    Thread.sleep(15000);
    System.out.println("After Sleep before Resume");
    mi.resumeMyTread();
    System.out.println("After resume before sleep");
    Thread.sleep(15000);
    System.out.println("After resume After sleep before Stop");
    mi.stopMyTread();
            
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.err.println("In Main Catch: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

here I am getting Output like,

> Starting thread: Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
>
> Background process successfully started.
>
> Sleeping...
>
> Processing
>
> Sleeping...
>
> Processing
>
> Sleeping...
>
> Pausing thread: Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
>
> After Pause before
>
> SleepThread successfully Paused.
>
> Processing
>
> After Sleep before Resume
>
> Resume thread: Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
>
> Sleeping...
>
> Processing
>
> Sleeping...
>
> Processing ............`Continue it is`
>
> `not run mi.stopMyTread()`;

any on solve it.. thanks.

Comment: Would this article help you at all? https://10kloc.wordpress.com/2013/12/24/cancelling-tasks-in-executors/

Comment: You are joining your thread in your `resumeMyTread`. Why?

Comment: Thanks for replying, i am using joining my thread for notifyAll().

Comment: Joining has nothing to do with `notifyAll`. `thread.join()` means "Pause the current thread (main thread in your case) until `thread` stops running.

Comment: Oops, its works when i remove `   try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("Exception In Pause"+ e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }` .   Thank You @RealSkeptic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I just remove,

```
try { 
    thread.join(); 
} catch (InterruptedException e) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    System.err.println("Exception In Pause"+ e);
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

from `resumeMyThread()` and it's fine. Thanks @RealSkeptic